# error in scalar multiplication

Tags: python, pandas, scalar

```
df6['Class4_Skim_Milk_Price'] = df6['Nonfat_Solids_Price'] * 9 

File "<ipython-input-32-aa3902291e41>", line 64
    df6['Class4_Skim_Milk_Price'] = (df6['Nonfat_Solids_Price'] * 9)
      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I am trying multiply one of the columns of the dataframe by 9 and trying to store it in new column of the data frame

Can you please guide me what wrong have I done?

Comment: How do you expect us to help you find a SyntaxError if you don't post your code....

Comment: df6['Class4_Skim_Milk_Price'] = df6['Nonfat_Solids_Price'] * 9

Comment: What is this df6['Nonfat_Solids_Price']? A string? Maybe you need to cast int(df6['Nonfat_Solids_Price'])

Comment: sorry I am new to stack overflow still learning how to go about it

Comment: As I and others have stated before and here. Please edit your question with raw data, code, any errors and the desired output. We don't have access to your machine

Comment: @Atirag if it were a string it would still not produce an error but concatenate many copies of the string.

Comment: This now looks like valid syntax. You need to post a few lines before that line I think. It could also be due to invisible characters from windows encoding.

Comment: The syntax for this single line is correct. Normally syntax errors are due to you have forgotten to close a parentheses, bracket, or string some lines above the line indicated on the traceback.

Please, post more of your core.

Comment: it just syntax error, Thanks for help, I will post in better manner from henceforth